# Using Java constants from Scala in Android

Tags: android, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a strange problem with developing in Scala on Android. I'm using sbt android plugin and right now I'm trying to get content providers working, but...

I need to get array of columns, and I'm doing it exactly like in tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Just replaced Java's array code with Scala one. It looks like this:

```
val projection = Array(
  People.NAME,
  People.NUMBER
)
```

But then, scala compiler returns error

```
[error] /home/exine/proj/hello-world/src/main/scala/Activity.scala:12: value NAME is not a member of object android.provider.Contacts.People
[error]     People.NAME,
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
```

And actually it *is* member of this object, and it's defined in interface android.provider.Contacts.PeopleColumns (which is implemented by People). I've tried getting it directly from PeopleColumns too without any success (same error). Is getting constants from Java in Scala somewhat different or I just made a stupid mistake somewhere?

UPDATE:

Next problem. When using ContactsContract.Contacts error stays the same, and when trying another method I can't access ContactsContract.ContactsColumns directly because it's protected interface.

```
[error] /home/exine/proj/hello-world/src/main/scala/Activity.scala:13: object ContactsColumns cannot be accessed in object android.provider.ContactsContract
[error]     ContactsColumns.LOOKUP_KEY,
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: For now, the best possible solution for it would be writing all query'ing code as class in java, and then calling it. It involves language mixing, increases complexity and it's something I don't like, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This context is deprecated according to the reference. The new way is `ContactsContract`, and you should use that.

Anyway, the problem is that this constant is a `static` defined on the `interface PeopleColumns`. Inheritance of statics is something that Java has but Scala doesn't, and it's frowned upon even in Java.

Try importing `PeopleColumns` and using `PeopleColumns.NAME` instead -- or, better yet, use the new, non-deprecated, way of doing things. Which I don't explain because I have no knowledge of Android development.

Comment: `[error] /home/exine/proj/hello-world/src/main/scala/Activity.scala:13: value NUMBER is not a member of object android.provider.Contacts.PeopleColumns
    [error]     PeopleColumns.NUMBER
    [error]                   ^
    [error] one error found` I'll try with new API.

Comment: @eXine `NUMBER` comes from `PhonesColumns`. As for the update... at that point, you'd best write something in Java to get around. Either the business logic when dealing with those interfaces, or some Scala-friendly Java wrapper around them. Both are bad options, but we seem to be running out of good options awfully fast.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for writing Java wrapper.

Comment: @exine Would love to see what you did about this, as I'm having the same problem.

The constant String values for the column names seem to be related to the variable names, for example the value of [ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#DISPLAY_NAME) is "display_name" so right now I'm using the literal column names instead of the names of the constants.  It's not too bad to look at, but if the values of the constants change I won't be in much of a position to complain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ll have to import static variables with `android.provider.Contacts.PeopleColumns._` before you can access them.

Comment: you have to call it directly as val projection = Array(
  NAME,
  NUMBER
)